# Make the "new answers to old questions" view available for people with <10000 reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, 10k-tools

Answers to old questions are often posted by new users that don't know yet how to use the site. Often these answers are badly formatted and need cleanup, but quickly drop from the front page and are forgotten. I feel like these posts could use some more eyes, since many pass by without anyone fixing them.

In the 10k tools there is a list of these posts and I think it would be a good idea to make this list available to more editors, like by lowering the reputation requirement to 5k.

Also "new post by new users" and "questions with newly created tags" might be candidates to make available at a lower rep threshold.

Comment: What are 10k tools? Did I miss something? And how exactly do you get the "new answers to old questions" view?

Comment: @divo: The "tools" link is in the top bar (where your rep is displayed), next to "log out" (only displayed on sites where you have >=10k reputation). There you get a few tabs with different kinds of information, the "new answers to old questions" link is on the "links" tab.

Comment: For future readers: The 10K tools have been removed since time ago. There is just a _review_ link, now.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Last time I had access to the privilege (a year ago) there was still a significant suite of 10k tools accessible via review -> tools. Or did you just mean that the topbar link is gone?

Comment: @NathanTuggy http://meta.stackexchange.com/tools is just a page with 4 links. The moderator tools where something different from that page. I remember I could get a page with flagged posts (not using a custom reason); a page with the the most up-voted posts, and the most down-voted posts; a page with the questions with the most close votes; a page with the migrated questions. Now, I can see that just as moderator.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, I was able to access all of those except flags. Only flags and one or two other things have been removed from 10k tools.

Comment: @kiamlaluno At least on SO they are still there. Here [/tools](/tools) shows less that SO for me, but at least it contains the info related to deletions (top delete/undelete votes, recent deletions). The top votes/... content I see on SO is missing on that page, but I also have less rep here, so maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Never mind... When /tools is shown, it doesn't show any sub-tab content. The pages are still there, but you need to first select a sub-tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's now the "Late Answers" review queue that fulfills the "more eyes" request.

Answer (score 5):

I would appreciate making this tool available to more users. I was not even aware of its existence, but it seems to be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

New answers to old questions would also help "late but good" answers get the attention they deserve. In fact I was going to request just such a view. It seems odd to me that only 10k users would have access to find these (underappreciated) answers. I would think we'd want to help the wiki-gnomes to find parts that need more (positive) attention.