# What are the review queues, and how do they work?

Tags: support, faq, review

I see a "review" link on the top of the page, which takes me to a few "review queues".

- What is a "review queue"?
- What are the various queues for?
- What can I do in each queue?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

### What is a "review queue"?

Review queues contain posts that possibly need community attention, as determined by the system or other members of the community. You are shown these posts, one at a time, and you "review" them. To incentivize reviewing, there are badges awarded for making a high number of reviews.

So, what constitutes a "review"? It depends on the queue. The queues have one consistent option, though — the **Skip** button. This permanently skips the post (you won't see it in the same review queue again, unless you pull it up in your review history) and is useful if you're not sure what to do.

Each user has their own copy of the queue — if you review a post in a queue, it is not necessarily removed from that queue for other users. It gets removed for all users after a few more reviews by other users (the exact amount [depends upon the queue and review action done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581)).

Note that in many cases, there may not be any items awaiting review in certain queues. If so, you'll get a "this queue has been cleared" message when attempting to review.

Before reviewing in any queues, **be sure you have a good grasp on what types of posts are considered within the site's guidelines** or what types of edits are acceptable. The best place to find this information is in the site's help center. Some sites may also have further guidance on how to review on their per-site metas.

### What are the various queues for, and what can I do in each?

Each review queue is designed to look at a certain aspect of the site at once, allowing users to interact with the community moderation process in different ways.

#### *Late answers*, *First answers*, and *First questions*

The *Late answers* queue contains answers which were posted much later than the question (and thus don't get as much attention; the purpose of this queue is to give them attention). The *First questions* and *First answers* queues contain the first question(s) and first answer(s) made by new users (who will probably need help learning to use the site), respectively. On sites with the Triage queue enabled, the *First questions* queue will also include questions deemed to require community editing (see *Site-specific queues* below).

In these queues, you can choose one of the following actions:

- **Looks OK**: the post meets the site's guidelines for good questions or answers (but you're not *that* impressed with the post to cast an upvote).
- **Edit**: the post may or may not meet the site's guidelines, but you can edit the post so it meets its guidelines or is of higher quality
- **Share feedback**: the post needs edits from the author in order to meet site guidelines. Only choose this option if the post does *not* meet site guidelines in its current state.
- **Other action**: Instead of choosing any of the above options, you can edit the post, flag it, vote on it, add your own comment, or upvote a previously existing comment. If you perform any of these actions, this button becomes available and you can finish your review.

You gain access to these queues with [access review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege (500 rep on sites with "full" requirements).

**Note:** These two queues do not exist on meta sites (thus [the listed reputation requirement to access review queues is higher here on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)).

For more guidance on how to review in these queues, see the dedicated FAQ posts [for First Questions and First Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030) and [for Late Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031).

#### *Low quality posts* or *Low quality answers*

The *Low quality posts* queue contains both questions and answers which were automatically determined to be of low quality based on several system criteria that generates a post quality score, or which have been [*flagged*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) by users for being extremely low quality or, in the case of answers, not being [proper answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). On sites with the *Triage* queue enabled, this queue is instead named *Low quality answers* and only consists of answers.

If you feel that a post is acceptable for the site and doesn't need to be improved further, choose **Looks OK**. Keep in mind that you can also post a comment before clicking this button.

If the post is **otherwise acceptable** other than a few formatting or grammar errors, you can choose **Edit** to improve the post, which dismisses the post from the review queue upon completion of your edits.

If the post cannot be salvaged or violates the site rules, you have two options depending on whether the post is a question or answer:

- **Close** for questions. Opens a menu that lets you choose a description for the problem that makes the question inappropriate (i.e. a reason for closing the question), and submits a vote to close the question.

  If you haven't earned the [close privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you'll be offered a **Recommend Close** option instead - this carries no vote on its own, but puts the question in the Close Votes queue for privileged users to vote to close (see "Close Votes" below).
- **Delete** for answers. Opens a menu that lets you choose a boilerplate comment to place, and casts a delete vote on the answer if you have enough reputation. You don't have to choose a comment, but if one fits the situation, then doing so is a courtesy to the author of the post you're deleting. The comment chosen will automatically be posted on your behalf (unless the same comment already exists), and will contain a link to the review task.

  If you haven't earned the [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege, you'll be offered a **Recommend Deletion** option instead - this will prioritize the review task for others who *can* vote to delete, and if a sufficient number of reviewers all recommend deletion, it can cause the answer to be either deleted (if its score is zero or negative), or forwarded to moderators for further review (if it has a positive score).

You gain access to this queue with the [ability to edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

This queue does not exist on per-site metas, but *does* exist on Meta Stack Exchange.

For more guidance on how to review in these queues, see [the dedicated FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029).

#### *Close votes*

The Close Votes queue contains questions with active votes or flags to close the question. Along with the moderator tools, this is one of the best ways to find questions that need closing.

On the top of the review item, you'll see the close reasons other users who voted or flagged the question for closure have chosen ("This question has been flagged as [close reason]"). If the duplicate reason is one of the chosen reasons, the "Duplicate [x]" tabs allow you to view the the duplicate target(s) proposed.

- If the question meets the criteria for any close reason (even if it's different from the one it was flagged as), and you cannot edit it so it's not closeable for any reason, choose **Close** and specify the close reason that most applies. This will cast a close vote.
- If the question as written is closeable for any reason, but you can edit it so that none of the close reasons apply, choose **Edit** to make edits. This will count the same as a review to leave open (see below).

  - On sites with "beta" reputation requirements, if you don't have the [privilege to edit questions and answers](/help/privileges/edit), you won't be shown this option.
- If the question doesn't meet the criteria for any close reason, choose **Leave open**. If enough users choose this option, the question will be dismissed from the review queue.

You gain access to this queue with the [ability to cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

For more guidance on how to review in this queue, see [the dedicated FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032).

#### *Reopen votes*

This queue contains closed questions with active reopen votes, questions that were edited after being closed and the editor specified that the edit addresses the reason for closure, and questions that were [deemed popular by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue) after closure.

In this queue, on the top, you'll be shown the reason for which the question has been closed, and, if the question was closed as a duplicate, tabs to see the question(s) it's closed as a duplicate of. If the question was edited after being closed, you'll also be shown a tab "Revision" indicating the edits that were made since it was closed. Be sure that you review the question itself, not merely the edit, in this case.

- If none of the close reasons apply to the question as it is currently written, choose **Reopen**. This will cast a reopen vote.
- If one or more close reasons still apply to the question (even though it may be a different reason from the one it's currently closed as), choose **Leave closed**.

  - If you do choose this option, you will be shown a menu to choose a reason why the question should still be closed. **Consider leaving a comment** to add more detail than what gets shown in the notice (e.g. why the edits, if any, were not sufficient to address the current close reason, why another close reason applies, or if the question should be closed as a duplicate, which other post answers/addresses the question).
  - **Don't simply choose this option if the only edits after closure were minor edits** — do be sure to check the question itself to ensure that close reason(s) still apply to it.
- If the question is closeable as written, but you can edit it so that none of the close reasons apply to it, choose **Edit and reopen** to make edits. This will also cast a reopen vote.

  - On sites with "beta" reputation requirements, if you don't have the [privilege to edit questions and answers](/help/privileges/edit), you will see this option; your edit will be submitted as a suggested edit.

You gain access to this queue with the [ability to cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

For more guidance on how to review in this queue, see [the dedicated FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450).

#### *Suggested edits*

Users without enough reputation to edit will have their edits placed in this queue.

If you feel that the edit is:

- **spam or vandalism**: it defaces the post, perhaps to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive
- **no improvement whatsoever**: the edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, find, or understand
- **clearly conflicts with author's intent**: it modified the post so that it may no longer be what the author meant it to be
- **attempt to reply**: it was intended to address the post author and should be a comment or an answer
- **irrelevant tags**: it introduces tags that do not help define the topic of the question
- **causes harm**: enter a custom reason

then **Reject** it as such.

If you reject as spam or vandalism, and even if other users agree by choosing the same, this is not recorded as a spam or vandalism flag in your Flag History on your profile. [Looking for post explaining why.] Clicking on "Flag" on the post itself will obviously not show a flag pending, because you didn't flag the post; you flagged the edit. The effort does count towards reviews completed, but not towards flags cast.

If the edit improves the post, and you can't make any improvements on top of it, click **Approve**.

Two reviews of the same type (two approvals, or two rejections) are required to dismiss the edit with that outcome.

You can also click the **Improve Edit** or **Reject and Edit**  buttons if you notice that the post has other things which need to be fixed. The Improve Edit option will start from the edit suggestion so you can make improvements on top of it, and counts the edit as an approved edit. On the other hand, the Reject and Edit option will start from the previous revision before the suggested edit and allow you to replace the suggestion with a different edit; the suggestion will be considered rejected. Both of these actions will immediately dismiss the review task.

Too many rejected suggested edits block a user from suggesting more for a while; keep this in mind while rejecting edits.

You gain access to this queue with the [ability to edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit). Suggested edits to tag wikis will also appear in the queue when you have the ["approve tag wiki edits" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), though you must have the ability to directly edit tag wikis (i.e. have the ["trusted user" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) in order to use the "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" options on those.

If you give the final approval, check to see if any comments can now be flagged as "no longer needed" based on the edit.

**See Also:** [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

For more guidance on how to review in this queue, see [the dedicated FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/997587).

#### Site-specific queues

**Triage**

This queue only shows up on certain sites (currently Stack Overflow and Physics). The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort questions into groups. Either:

- the question is good, on-topic, and high-quality, or
- the question needs some community editing for grammar, spelling, and formatting, but is otherwise a good fit for the site, or
- the question needs additional information from the author to be a good fit for the site, or
- the question isn't a good fit for the site and can't be fixed by the author or the community.

For more information, see [the documentation for the Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue), or see [the dedicated FAQ post on guidance for reviewing in the triage queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370715).

#### Old, discontinued queues

The following queues have existed in the past, but no longer exist or have been superseded today.

**Site Self-Evaluation**

This was mainly for beta sites, to evaluate the quality of the collective base of questions and answers on that site and compare it to other sites on the Internet.

On the 60th day of beta, and for every 180 days (originally 90 days) after that, this queue was filled with a set of posts (picked [more or less randomly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161033/178438)), which were to be evaluated individually as "Excellent", "Satisfactory", or "Needs Improvement" compared to other online resources addressing the same thing. The results of these evaluations were shown to moderators, who could gauge how well the overall quality of the site is compared to other web sites.

This queue [formerly turned up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166036/178438) on graduated sites as well, but was [disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165994/community-evaluation-on-established-sites/166036#166036) for them in February 2013. It [was shut down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261601/shutting-down-recurring-community-self-evaluations) for beta sites in July 2015.

**Help and Improvement**

The goal of Help and Improvement was to edit questions that were deemed to require community editing in Triage (i.e. are placed as part of the second of the four groups specified in its section).

In this queue, one could either edit the question to proofread or otherwise increase the quality of the post, or state that the question was not a good fit for the site ("question is very low quality").

For more information, see [the original announcement for Help and Improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue). The queue was [shut down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/377214) in August 2021 and tasks deemed to require community editing in Triage now instead go to the *First questions* queue.

### Can I earn badges?

Yes, you can earn badges for reviewing. Each of the following badges are awarded per-queue, and so can be earned multiple times by satisfying the criteria in different queues:

- [Custodian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/custodian) (bronze), for making your first review in a particular queue, awarded once per queue
- [Reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/169/reviewer) (silver), for making 250 reviews in a specific queue, awarded once per queue
- [Steward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward) (gold), for making 1,000 reviews in a specific queue, awarded multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in the same queue

Additionally, the [Proofreader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/proofreader) badge (bronze) is awarded once for making 100 reviews in the Suggested Edits queue specifically.

You can track the number of reviews you've made in a particular queue and your progress toward the above badges by clicking the "Stats" tab in the top right.

### Why did I receive a message saying that a review task was a test to make sure I was paying attention?

Unfortunately, on many sites, many users simply approve everything without actually looking at the tasks. As a result, "audit" tasks may be mixed in to discourage users from being *robo-reviewers*.

For more about review audits, how they work, and how to report bad audits, see [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121).

### See also

- [What are review queues?](/help/reviews-intro) in the help center, which links to basic instructions on how to review
- [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) here on Meta, which has more detailed instructions on how to review

Comment: @AustinHenley MSO should [likely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying) have a **Last post** queue

Comment: I read elsewhere that you don't get a 'Review' link until you have reached 1000 rep, yet there are queues to which you have access well before that rep level (i.e., most of the ones mentioned in this post). How are you supposed to access those once you have the rep to be able to do so? Wouldn't it have been better to have the 'Review' link once you are able to access at least one queue and then have that page show only the queues to which you have access?

Comment: @RobH No, now it's at 125 rep I think. That was the old review queue.

Comment: @Manishearth: So, where's the link to the queues, then? Isn't there supposed to be one if you have enough rep?

Comment: @RobH On the top of the screen.

Comment: I don't see any review links there or anywhere else. My links at the top are Chat, Main/Meta, About and Help. That's it. (I'd ask you for a screen shot, but it seems that this site hosts them on imgur, which our corporate firewall blocks, so that won't work.)

Comment: @RobH Do you have 125 rep on the site?

Comment: I have 764 on SO and 307 on Meta, so if the link is supposed to appear when I have at least 125, then I should certainly see it on both sites.

Comment: @RobH Huh. That's a bug, I think. It should be near the chat link.

Comment: I just had another look, and I now see the link on SO, but still not in Meta.

Comment: @RobH Meta only has  edit/close/reopen queues, so you'll need 2k rep

Comment: You say "the queue fills" every 90 days for beta sites, but I don't see the queue at all (for Pets beta). Is it possible that the queue's only shown then and not other times? I can see all the queues and the ones I aren't able to access yet are greyed out so I don't think it's a reputation thing (unless this queue is handled differently from the others in that regard).

Comment: @RobH do you get any rep from reviewing

Comment: @IPADDRESS: To be honest, I don't know, as I've actually not done any reviews yet. (There never seems to be any time.) You'd have to do some reviews yourself and see if that affects your rep.

Comment: @RobH I was asking because that is my next privilege and i was thinking if you gain rep then its something to look forward too, right?

Comment: @IPADDRESS: There doesn't seem to be any mention of rep gain (or loss) due to reviewing in [this article in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). You might want to try asking one of the mods or other long timers to be certain.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it doesn't touch upon the Triage queue. I think its description should also be added.

Comment: As Suseika mentioned, Triage is missing. Now I miss also Help & Improvement.

Comment: Triage is experimental right now, right?

Comment: @Manish should we delete the section for "community eval"s, since they are no more?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M sure

Comment: Please add info on timing to expect: when does a post become available in the review queue? I frequently see posts that should be reviewed, even have eg close-votes gathered already, that do not show up in my queues for minutes/hours, I don't know.

Comment: If a question is in my review-queue, how long will be it before it's moved to someone else's queue? Such a situation can occur when we are away from the site.

Comment: The way you are banned x days from reviewing is counterproductive. You earn the privilege, you dedicate time to review. If you make error (I made 3 over 600 reviews), you are banned X days. Remind me old school. Change your way of interacting with user that are doing their best to help this site. NB : I stop reviewing