# How review queue is assigned?

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the review queues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)

Normally i can't do anything for reviews, because my queue is often empty. How this assign works? and why there's nothing on FAQ about it?

Comment: The FAQ can't include everything, it's meant for the ordinary users who come to ask questions. Anyway I agree it's not trivial to find such information. General rule is look on Meta for relevant tag ([meta-tag:review]) in this case and sift through the posts. If too many posts look for that tag plus [meta-tag:faq] and you'll see specific faq(s) for that topic. The dupe can be found easily [this way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review+faq).