# "Community Evaluation" on established sites

Tags: support, status-bydesign, review, site-evaluation

If the **Community Evaluation** review queue is only for beta sites to help determine if/when the site is ready for graduation (so it says in the answer to [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)) why has it suddenly appeared on [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), which graduated from beta ages ago?

Is this a policy change or a technical glitch?

Comment: This is probably a glitch, but I think it'll be a good idea to run community evals on graduate sites (less often than betas, of course).

Comment: It's on Physics as well (Probably started Feb 1 UTC on both?).  I've updated the faq to reflect this. I don't think it's a glitch, since there wasn't any statement _denying_ that this happens. Aside from that, one of the sites the queue was tested on before it was rolled out was Ask Ubuntu, a graduated site.

Comment: Well, it does say "This review queue appears periodically on sites to evaluate the overall quality of the Q&A." Maintaining quality over time is just as important as starting off on the right foot.

Comment: @Tim: Indeed, but this just appeared on two sites I frequent quite a bit and I'd never seen it before. (Or even heard of it, and I try to stay on top of things here on Meta.) What little information I could find when I went searching said it was for sites currently in beta.

Comment: I believe it's a stand-in for [these kind of manual evaluations](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/evaluate-your-site-a-check-for-quality).

Comment: I think they're indirectly telling you that allowing [webapps.se] to graduate was a mistake ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is new. Now that we no longer have to run site evaluations manually ourselves, we figured  we would expand them to graduated sites.

Tim Stone hit the nail on the head in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165994/community-evaluation-on-established-sites#comment485273_165994):

> Maintaining quality over time is just as important as starting off on the right foot.

Now, this *is* somewhat experimental. If these evaluations prove too distracting or not particularly helpful on graduated sites, we'll turn them off. In the meantime, the queue should pop up for a week every 90 days.

---

**Update:** after reviewing the results and responses across the network, we have disabled these evaluations for graduated sites. If specific communities want to do a periodic spot check of their own, we can fairly easily provide a random sample set of questions to them, but otherwise... y'all are "free and clear" once the beta period ends. :)

Comment: Feature request (should I post it separately?): don't do it for every site at once. For those of us who participate on several sites, it's a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @Gilles Don't worry about posting it separately. There's probably always going to be some overlap (we have a lot of sites), but I'll see what we can do.

Comment: @Gilles If I recall correctly, there will always be several sites running simultaneously, but not *all* sites will run together. So, 5 sites might have evals going at any given time, but it'll be rare indeed if all 90+ have an eval running.

Comment: @Aarthi Aren't all non-trilogy sites having an eval right now? At least all the ones I participate on.

Comment: @Gilles *Almost* all. There are a few that aren't running right now for various reasons. We'll stagger future ones a bit better.