# Where is the operation of the /review queue documented for users?

Tags: support

I've got a few users that have needed guidance on how the /review queue works and am looking to find where it is documented so that I can point them to the mechanics of how it is intended to work.

Specifically, I'm looking for the mechanics of how things are supposed to work on the following:

- close queue
- open queue
- first post

These are the queues that I'm seeing the most difficulty for new users to "get". I'm looking for a very short "this is how it works" and then a almost as short - your job is to X while you are in this queue. The review tabs have some nice guidance when there is a review task in queue, but I can't figure out how to link to that text (or a suitable equivalent) when those queues are empty.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues

Comment: @Oded shazam! WTF can't I find that after searching three times - last night and just now?

Comment: I went to the top related question (scored of 1150 at the moment) and searched for `review` on that page...

Comment: PS - A search for `[review][faq]` only [returns 2 results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review+faq).

Comment: @animuson Bingo. Even once I asked it - it was one of the top links - just not until I asked did I find where it was and be able to work backwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)

For whatever reason, I didn't see this post when searching (and that [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is quite large with many review related items).

Thanks to [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) for the quick tip in locating the main documentation. As far as the "users can't see the answer from the /review page" part, I'll work on that aspect by agitating to include links to the answer from the text on the review page rather than relying on users to find this or the actual wording of "what are the review queues" and being a better meta searcher than I.