# What exactly is a "late answer"?

Tags: support, review

I'm currently learning more about the review queues.

When I look at the Late Answers queue, I understand (in part [thanks to this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)) that the Late Answers queue finds "old" posts that have a new answer on them (usually from a low-rep or new user) and puts them into the queue for review.

I understand the purpose (to check for spam in an easy way) but I'm curious:

- What's the cutoff for "lateness" -- that is, how old does a question have to be before new answers posted to it are considered "late answers" ?
- Is there a second check for the answering user's reputation level?

I checked the queue itself, tooltips on the three queue and stats pages, as well as did a quick search on meta but didn't find these answers delineated anywhere.

[EDIT]: The "youngest" post we've found in the Late Answers queue has been 35 days old. Is the cutoff possible >30 Days?