# Allow everyone read-only access to hidden reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, privileges

You need at least 3k reputation to review Close Votes -- yes, sounds reasonable (although 3k is a little high, but that's not what this is about).

I could learn a lot about how SO works if I could read the review threads. I understand not being able to participate until I've displayed that I'm a good citizen (although I do, truly, think that being considered guilty until proven innocent is an *absolutely disgusting* policy), but I don't understand why you hold these deliberations behind closed doors.

Surely you guys have noticed that the open societies around you are the most successful, and the societies that base privileges on status and who keep their governance behind locked doors, open only to a few anointed individuals are doomed to end in flames...

So, can you allow at least read-only access to the court records please? I'd be ever so thrilled.

Comment: Remember that downvotes have a different meaning on meta -- they indicate whether people agree with your feature request or not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ernest, I didn't know that.

Comment: trust me you wont find anything interesting in close vote queue

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I'd have to disagree there. I've seen the odd interesting question in the Close Votes queue. Some of them still need to be closed; some are highly upvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have a look at recently closed questions, just do a search for:

```
closed:1
```

You can optionally include tags if you want to see questions of a particular type, e..g.:

```
closed:1 [php]
```

The best way to grok the review system is to see the results that it produces, which (in this case) will be a steady stream of questions that have been closed. There's no real deliberation or coordination in the process, users are just presented with questions and asked to take whatever action is appropriate.

Looking at what has been closed is actually where the open discussion has an opportunity to take place - was something closed that probably should not have been? Did you find a question that you could answer but was closed due to being too ambiguous? Do you have a few minutes to suggest some edits? Does a closure look so erroneous that it should be brought up here on Meta?

Concluding - you don't actually need access to the queue in order to get involved with the *process*, there's plenty of opportunity for follow up activity, and perform additional checks to make sure the right stuff is getting closed.

Comment: Thanks @TimPost. I had no idea what was behind those links, so I supposed it was a discussion on whether something need be closed or not. Like I said, I just want to learn how to use SO and watching the seniors seems like a good strategy.

Comment: FYI for anyone trying to do the search - When searching for Tim's first example, I had to do it without the brackets, e.g. **Closed:1** and NOT **[Closed:1]**. When I use the brackets, the system tries to search tags. In the second example above **php** is actually a tag, so the search terms would be: **Closed:1 [php]**

Comment: @chuex Doh - you'd think by now I'd know how to use search both before and after my first cup of coffee. Fixed.

Answer (score 9):

> I don't understand why you hold these deliberations behind closed doors.

Deliberations? Reviewing close votes is merely looking at a question and determining whether *you* think the question should be closed, left open, or edited. If you can't decide, you can skip it. There is no "deliberating" involved - users cannot talk to one another in the review queues.

Further than that, not even users with close vote privileges can see records of what other users have done in the review queues. The history tab they have access to only lists out *their* past reviews. You don't gain access to view history of others until you receive your 10k privileges. Even then, there's not *much* to look at.

Comment: You may be right, but your tone indicates that this is something I aught to have known. How can it be known if it's being done 'in secret', whether that's intentional or not?

Comment: @EngineerDollery: They work pretty much in the same way as the other queues you already have access to view, just with different options for action. If you're interested in learning about review, there's plenty of information regarding the close and reopen votes queues in the [close votes privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions). There's also an extensive post about [review in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) here on Meta. Information *about* the review queues is plentiful, only actual access to them is restricted.

Answer (score 4):

The Close Votes section is nothing fascinating. There are 54 or so thousand questions waiting to be reviewed for a reason.

I don't see why this should be implemented at all. Your only reasons are so you can see what the process is like and learn how SO works. There are other ways:

- Do other review tasks. You have access to First Posts and Late Answers. If you see a post which is inaccurate, flag it! You have flags for a reason, and I'm sure using these correctly will help you learn about SO.
- Explore SO. It's big, so find some questions and answers that may help you learn. See previously closed questions and figure out why they were closed.

Comment: Also, this is my first answer to meta. So apologies if I did something wrong