# Can a question that is on hold be reopened?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

Can a question which is on hold be reopened? I've edited the post, will it be opened again?

My post is here:
[enhancing my JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931891/how-are-java-applets-beneficial-while-they-are-slower-than-internet-edited-titl)
It is under hold now. What should I do?

Comment: thanks brother should I delete this question?

Comment: @CreatedC Some duplication is a good thing, its up to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question that is on hold and is edited by it's author (or another user) will be submitted to the [reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues). From that point users with the close/reopen vote privilege will vote upon it to reopen it or keep it closed. If it gains 5 reopen votes it will be reopened. So whether it will be reopened is entirely down to the quality of your edit.

Comment: FYI: [this was what happened](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2974044) when it was in the queue.