# What is the most efficient way to get a review task?

Tags: support, review

The question [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) explains what reviews are, but it doesn't say how to get one.

If I wait in the page for reviews (https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers for example), will I eventually see a review? 
Should I refresh the page like that would save my life?
Should I clicking around like a squirrel looking for the last nut until one pops into the queue?

What is the most efficient way to get a review task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script) called Review Stalker, which will refresh the page and change the title if reviews are available.

Please only use this if you're genuinely trying to improve the site through reviews.

Comment: How not to love SO? First I find out you can run SQL against SO, now I learn you can run scripts against it. Awesome.