# What is the purpose of the reviews filter under the activity tab of the network profile?

Tags: support, review, profile-page, network-profile

What is listed under Network Profile -> activity -> reviews?

This section of [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3083067/john-sonderson?tab=activity) is currently empty.

I would like to know what it is used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for results of your reviews of some items in specific tasks. The review tasks are located (for example) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (its is `/review` on any SE site); if you have sufficient<sup>*</sup> reputation, you can review some tasks. The result of your review will be added to "reviews" section.

Further reading: [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

<sup><sup>*</sup> - you can review [suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) regardless of your rep if they are suggested on your post; those reviews also added to this "reviews" section</sup>

Comment: Thanks. The link you posted was very helpful.