# Answer deleted by low quality review queue, for how long I can see other's deleted answer

Tags: support, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

I was recommended to delete an answer from the low quality review queue on `Feb 1`. If I visit to my [low quality review queue history tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) still I can see the deleted answer. As I aware 10K+ users can able to see the deleted posts, not the users less than 10K.

Is there any limited period of time (like 60 days for deleted recent answers) only I can able to see the deleted answer or for always?

I cross-checked this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), didn't get the reference.