# When reviewing, what to do when previous reviewer has already posted a comment?

Tags: support, review

On a recent review of a first post the previous reviewer, a moderator, had already posted a comment that covered the issue.

The post was asked on the wrong SE site, but their comment covered this.

I decided to flag for moderator intervention because the 'No action necessary' pop-up for this action says "This question seems to be valid", which it isn't on the site it was posted on. But, a moderator was already aware as they commented so is flagging it just making work for others, or is this correct action?

I have done some looking around on the Metas but can't find an answer to this I don't think?

[What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

[How does the new user question review process work?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-does-the-new-user-question-review-process-work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to flag it, you can always upvote the previous reviewer's comment and then click on "I'm done".

Comment: Oh, ok, yes I see. That is a good idea.