# How does a post end up in the review queue?

Tags: support, review, data-explorer, database-design

I've read about Review Tasks [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work?newreg=3e030237408948cb8b8d66a27ebee6cf) and examined the tables [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

My questions are:

1. What kinds of posts get to the review table? (E.g., questions, answers,..)
2. What is the qualifying factor?
3. Who/what sends them to the review queue? (Does the user push a button, men-in-black, algorithm?)

I'm referring to SEDE and in particular task related tables.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific review queue? There are lots of them.

Comment: @Oded There's a table called 'ReviewTasks'. That's the one am referring to. I believe this is the main one that houses all reviews before heading to SuggestEdits, Close requests?

Comment: @JohnMiller that's just a static table in SEDE, not live. It's just a mirror copy. You better edit the question and explain you mean the SEDE table, not actual review.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks alot. I've updated it.

Answer (score 4):

> What kinds of posts get to the review table? (Ex. Questions, answers,..)

Yes, questions and answers. Tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts too. Depends on the queue.

> What is the qualifying factor?

Depends on the queue. For example - suggested edit queue will get all suggested edits. Close queue will get posts that have gotten close votes or suggested close votes. First post queue will get the first post that a user has posted... etc.

> Who/what sends them to the review queue? (Does the user push a button, men-in-black, algorithm?)

This is automatic - there's an algorithm for each queue that fetched matching posts and puts them in the queue.