# Why was there no review task generated for my first answer on a site?

Tags: bug, review

I've asked a similar question before: [Why are there no review tasks generated for a couple of my recent First Posts on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327350/295232) but that has been fixed. Yesterday, I posted my [first answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/622283/113522) on a site but again it didn't get reviewed. Did the bug regress, or was this answer skipped because I was over a certain reputation threshold already (due to repairing broken images)? I've written a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/1602221) to list the review items of that day; looking at timestamps, it *could* have been the task with ID 318365, but that got deleted (or not created at all) somehow.

I checked my deleted answers and questions on that site already, but there were none.

Comment: System knows Glorfindel need no revision.

Comment: Related (but no definitive answer, e.g. the application or not of a quality filter): *[How does a post end up in the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302777/)*

Comment: Per [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-completed-or-invalidated), if the author's reputation is 125 or higher, any *First answers* review tasks will be invalidated. (Source for my edit there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369765/377214)

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog thanks, that clarifies a bit; still, invalidated review tasks *are* visible in the [timeline](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/622283/timeline), so it doesn't explain 100% of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The criteria for a post *entering* a review queue are always the same as the criteria for [what would cause it to be invalidated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-completed-or-invalidated).

The review queues are populated by running a query for all posts matching those criteria. If any are found that do not yet have a review task for them, the system creates a new one. Any existing, active review tasks that are not in that list get invalidated. There aren't separate criteria, and it all runs off the same query.

Your answer wasn't eligible because you already had 125 reputation on the site - it never appeared in the list to have a task created.

Comment: So in this case he gained upvotes/an accept before the script ran?

Comment: @Luuklag He already had 1,000 reputation from suggested edits.