# Why can't I review posts?

Tags: support, review

A few days ago I earned a privilege; now I have access to a review queue for First Posts and Late Answers.

I got a notification that from now onward I can review First Posts and Late Answers from users.

Check the screenshot below:

[image]

But every time I check there I can't find any questions that I can review.

I don't know much more about this. Can anyone help me regarding this?

If I can't review First Posts and Late Answers, then what does the above image mean?

Comment: Can you please explain the specific error message you get? Is it "this queue has been cleared"?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog, Yes Everytime I checked there I saw this Queue has been cleared.

Comment: On some sites that's pretty normal on those queues - because a lot of people can review them they get cleared quickly. There's no reviews of any kind waiting on Magento at the moment.

Comment: Ohh I See. So What does is exactly mean ? Correct me If i am wrong, Like any new user posts their first question on MSE (Magento SE) than I have rights to review their post ?  If i managed to reach there before senior moderator !!?

Comment: Yes that's right, you'll just need to keep checking it fairly often. There's a red dot that appears but only if one of the queues is getting somewhat large. Maybe just open the all queues page from time to time and see what's there.

Comment: Hahaa Good Thanks @PeterJ

Comment: Shameless plug: I wrote [a script specifically to make it easier to routinely check for available reviews](https://stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded-a-cross-site-dashboard-for-reviews).

Comment: related [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento is a medium-sized Stack Exchange site, with not as many first-time users as e.g. Stack Overflow. There were only 6 First Posts reviews so far today (in the 7.5 hours since 0:00 UTC); you can see this on the [stats page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats):

[image]

For comparison, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) already saw [574](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2LA7.png). So just wait a bit more and eventually you'll get something to review. When I started reviewing, I used Nathan's [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded-a-cross-site-dashboard-for-reviews) so that I didn't continually need to refresh the /review page, which increases the chance that you get to review something. Thanks for displaying the eagerness to help the site forward; please treat new users the way you would've liked to be treated when you were new and remember that [there's no shame in using Skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/4751173).

---

I digress a bit but with this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/865863/number-of-first-posts-and-late-answers-per-week#graph) you can get a better idea of how many reviews there are per *week* on Magento. (Per day gives a graph which is more bumpy; also, on the weekends there are usually less posts.)

[image]

Comment: That' very helpful information. Now I understood. :)