# Is it bad to skip a lot of suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Often if there's a change in code and I don't know the language, then I don't want to risk approving an edit that changes the code from working to not working.

Is it bad to skip a lot of suggested edits? Or is it considered bad and does the system penalise this? Suppose more are skipped than approved, improved, and rejected combined

Comment: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: 1st question: better safe than sorry, 2nd: ***someone*** must do them or, 3rd: they just pile up and a possibly helpful edit doesn't go through - think how you would feel waiting forever. --- But, if you don't know, stay out of it; not enough people skip things they ought to. --- More of an opinion, than an official answer.

Comment: Also you can filter the queue on tags you are familiar with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it bad to skip a lot of suggested edits?

No, it's perfectly fine to do so. Better to skip a post in the review queue than to approve a bad suggested edit / reject a good one. Just review the ones you feel confident about.

> Or is it considered bad and does the system penalise this?

No, the system doesn't penalize skipping posts. The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/377968) explains the "skip" option:

> The queues have one consistent option, though — the "skip" option. This permanently skips the post (you won't see it in the same review queue again, unless you pull it up in your review history) and is useful if you're not sure what to do.

The only effect it has is that you won't get to see the skipped post again. No penalty (but also no reward, i. e. no completed review).

Answer (score 7):

> Is it bad to skip a lot of suggested edits? Or is it considered bad and does the system penalise this?

No, AFAIK that's the right action to do if you're unsure, or aren't familiar with the question domain.

If you skip, it's just like you didn't touch the post at all (besides viewing it).

Comment: No, skip doesn't count as a review. You can skip the whole CVQ on SO and still have 40 close review tasks left ....

Comment: @rene THX for the clarification. I am not working with the review queues at all.