# Why do very old posts appear in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue?

Tags: support, review, flags, low-quality-posts

According to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/643262), the "Low Quality Posts" review queue is populated with posts that are either automatically suspected by the system to be low quality, or by posts that have been flagged as low quality.

I recently got a 7-year-old posts in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. I would assume that, if an automated algorithm determines the post to be in need of review for low quality, it would have made that decision already 7 years ago. So I believe this was the result of a flag.

**Question**: am I right to believe that all very old posts in the "Low Quality Posts" queue are there because of a flag, or can it happen that the automatic algorithm suddenly changes criterion and marks an old post as low quality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, it must have been a manual flag. Note that [after 7 days it's not possible to mark a post as 'Very Low Quality'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/4751173), so we even know that somebody must have cast a 'Not an Answer' flag; both flags feed the same review queue.

> **Question:** am I right to believe that all very old posts in the "Low Quality Posts" queue are there because of a flag, or can it happen that the automatic algorithm suddenly changes criterion and marks an old post as low quality?

As far as I know, the automatic algorithm only checks new posts. (♦ moderators can see who flagged a post; the automatic algorithm also casts flags which are attributed to the Community user.) I have yet to see an automatic low quality flag on an existing post.