# Why not completely hide closing/reopen votes during a voting process?

Tags: feature-request, voting

What do you think of "adding" the following feature :

Removing completely the ability for users to see, until a vote has ended, whether or not other people close/reopen/...-voted a question (and obviously inability to see the reason). I'm not talking of the main voting system here.

Motivation: I have the feeling a people look at the votes, and will be influenced in what information is already there to make their choice.
A bit like for a jury for some competition, its bad that information is shared during or before the voting process. It's all good if that information is fully available afterwards. 
This way, there is more independence in the process, and people will determine their vote only based on their assessment of the content, and not based on other people's votes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Well it is certainly very related. But my question was more pragmatic, perhaps more focusing on closing and reopen votes. Not really the main voting system

Comment: Hiding information, (this is called lying), rarely ends well.  For example, users' rep is not allowed to drop below 1 - I suspect that is one reason that so many new users tend to miss/ignore/whatever notifications and emails that warn of an approaching ban, (that, and that users forget about the burner gmail account they used to sign up:)

Comment: there was similar experiment at Stack Overflow: they tried to hide down-votes / negative post score. [Results weren't encouraging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393923/839601)

Comment: There is an easier solution, users need to write better questions, instead of questions that end up being closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a proposal to be in any way effective, it would also have to encompass eliminating the [close and reopen vote review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/242059), and realistically that won't happen -- those queues are an integral part of the curation mechanisms of the sites, warts and all.

In addition, consider that visibility cuts both ways. Hiding existing votes would make it harder for interested observers to take action to prevent questions which should remain open from being closed.