# Hide comments in audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, review-audits

[image]
As shown, there is a comment which said, "Repeat Spammer. Flagged as spam." But the answer was posted few days ago, so this would have been deleted. So I immediately knew that this was an audit. Could all comments be disabled on audits?

Comment: Audits are only to make sure you are paying attention. In this case because you observed the comment and realized it was spam, the audit did its job and you would pass. I don't think they need to be more difficult, there are already other ways to tell if  it is an audit or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) (specifically, the "A review is obviously an audit. Should I report it?" section)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do more harm than good. Often, when reviewing, you will find a problem with the post and want to let the OP know about the problem by writing a comment. You will then look at the existing comments, and it happens often that someone else has already said what you wanted to say. For example,

> what have you tried?

> is this a homework question?

> what is your location?

are very common comments that might already be there. In that case, you will want to upvote that comment instead of repeating it. The [guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/643262) for the "First posts" review queue explicitly mentions upvoting existing comments as one of the possible ways of completing a review:

> In these queues, you can edit the post, flag it, vote on it, add a comment, **or upvote a previously existing comment**.

Therefore, being able to see existing comments is often useful for the reviewer. Even seeing existing answers is usually helpful.

Comment: It was in low quality posts. I will add link.