# How does this close votes review have 5 votes already but is still open?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I was going through the close votes review queue on Arqade, and came across [this review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/319350) which apparently has 5 votes to close already (the number needed to close a post on Arqade), yet its still in the queue:

[image: review]

You can see the possible duplicate comment has 6 upvotes, one of which is from me (note - I am a moderator of Arqade, and I often will upvote these comments when I agree with them rather than mod-close out the question to encourage the community to make a decision instead).

I noticed on the [history of the post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/398393/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) there are four votes to close, and one flag.  Is the *flag* counting towards this?  Are they suppose to?

Comment: The [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) FAQ mentions: *On the top of the review item, you'll see the close reasons other users who voted or **flagged** the question for closure have chosen*. "Is the flag counting towards this?" This does seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Justin I suppose that answers that.  Although - the tool tip for the `(5)` is somewhat misleading to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRNtk.png.  It says it received 5 **votes**, while really its 4 votes and 1 flag.

Comment: Well the faq answers this question, and you can start a feature request asking to change the misleading tooltip.

Comment: Made a feature request https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380757/can-the-tool-tip-for-the-close-votes-review-number-be-changed-to-denote-the-amou