# Can the tool tip for the close votes review number be changed to denote the amount of votes and the amount of flags?

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, vote-to-close, tooltips

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380755/how-does-this-close-votes-review-have-5-votes-already-but-is-still-open) where I noticed that the review item had a "(5)" for the number of "votes" it received to be closed.  It confused me, since 5 votes on Arqade is what you need to close a post, yet the post was still open/in the review queue.

The tooltip of the "(5)" states "This close reason received 5 votes":

[image: tooltip]

This is technically not the case.  It has [four close *votes* and one recommend for closure *flag*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/398393/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries):

[What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) states that:

> On the top of the review item, you'll see the close reasons other users who voted or flagged the question for closure have chosen

But the tooltip is misleading.  Can the tooltip be updated to say how many votes **and** how many flags it has? Or maybe better yet, can we have two numbers displayed in parenthesis where one is for the votes, and one is for flags or perhaps two numbers that are labelled like:

> Votes: (number); Flags (number)

**Note**: there is also a chance it used to show only the actual close votes in the past, so back then the tooltip was correct, and due to a bug the text changed to show count of both close votes and flags, hence adding [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) here as well.

Comment: Yeah, showing the count under "votes" is pretty ambiguous. One can *deduce* what it means, but having these split would be really nice, and would much more clearly indicate how close to closure the particular question is. Tooltips in general aren't too discoverable, I much prefer your second recommendation to show both the current CVs and the current recommended-closure flag count, split.

Comment: Thinking about it, the amount of flags it less relevant, it has no real effect. So another option is to display only the amount of actual close votes, then the tooltip will be correct.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I'm pretty sure that's how it *used* to be, right? Call me crazy, but I remember the old review UI only displaying the current close votes in its header panel.

Comment: I'd also be fine if it only displayed the vote number too (so don't count the flags at all)

Comment: @Spevacus no idea, really didn't pay attention to it in the past. But yeah, can add [tag:bug] tag here as well and dev handling it will remove either that or the feature request tag depends on what's really going on.

Comment: What is the purpose of that tooltip exactly? Wouldn't it be better and more accessible to just explain the number in the notice in more detail? I really don't like tool tips with no button on web pages. If they aren't redundant, they end up hiding information from people on touch devices.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree the tooltip isn't the best.  As stated, something like "Votes: (number); Flags (number)" would be ideal.