# Is the Low Quality review queue missing from (LawSE) Meta?

Tags: bug, review

LawSE is the only site where I can view review queues, so I cannot say if this is network wide...

The Help Centre section entitled [What are review queues?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro) includes this:

> (Note: The *First questions*, *First answers*, and *Late answers* queues do not exist on Meta sites.)

But Low Quality doesn't exist there either:

[image]

despite the ability to flag questions as such:

[image]

Comment: LQ review doesn't exist on meta sites. Such flags appear to be sent to the moderator-only queue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) -- _"Low Quality Posts does not exist on per-site metas, but does exist on Meta Stack Exchange."_

Comment: Perhaps the Help Center article should be edited to mention this.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yep, just trying to work out the best way to do it...