# The Help Center is missing detail concerning Low Quality review queues not on per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, help-center, low-quality-posts

Further to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381412/906208), this [FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/906208) states:

> Low Quality Posts does not exist on per-site metas

However, this detail is absent from the Help Center section entitled [What are review queues?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro):

> (Note: The *First questions*, *First answers*, and *Late answers* queues do not exist on Meta sites.)

Can the Help Center be updated accordingly?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, since while it doesn't exist on per-site metas, it *does* exist on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: There's also the issue of the help center pages having to be the same across the network. On sites with the Triage queue (currently SO and Physics, but can change), the queue is called *Low quality answers* instead of *Low quality posts*, and the Triage queue also doesn't exist on their meta sites.