# Is it "Low quality answers" or "low quality posts"?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, wording

I haven't visited Stack Overflow's review queues in a while, but this morning I did (thanks [winter-bash-2022](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2022)!), and noticed that unlike other sites I request (Super User, Open Source SE), Stack Overflow's Low quality posts queue is actually called "Low quality answers":

[image: Low quality answers on Stack Overflow]

Clicking on the "Learn more" link pops up a modal explaining about "Low quality answers:

[image: Low quality answers popup on Stack Overflow]

But clicking on the "Read more" link there goes to a Help Center article "How do I use the Low quality **posts** queue?":

[image: Low quality posts in Help Center]

So which one is it? "Low quality posts" or "Low quality answers"?

Comment: Per the FAQ [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work): *On sites with the* Triage *queue enabled, this queue is instead named* Low quality answers *and only consists of answers.*

Comment: Consistency was never the strong side of SE. And SO was never really part of SE network of sites, more like a skyscraper standing alone and watching over all the others far below, full with shining features they'll never get.

Comment: There must be an existing meta question about this. Isn't it to do with the [Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) being specific to Stack Overflow? Or due to some review queues having been split, merged, or added (specific to Stack Overflow)? Or in other words, there is a good reason for it.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Chasing Stars: That ***wasn't*** the real change (only secondary). The real change was spacing for the last image ("formatting"). Please review properly before making such negative statements.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Low quality posts or Low quality answers
The Low quality posts queue contains both questions and answers which were automatically determined to be of low quality based on several system criteria that generates a post quality score, or which have been flagged by users for being extremely low quality or, in the case of answers, not being proper answers. On sites with the Triage queue enabled, this queue is instead named Low quality answers and only consists of answers.". --- If that isn't clear it can be edited.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars They use an [automated editing tool](//pmortensen.eu) which applies a bunch of other general "fixes" (including capitalizing image descriptions) to every post they edit, on top of the one they intend to make.

Comment: @Sonic I strongly dislike automated tools doing what humans should do themselves, but that's besides the point. Such edit is worthless and useless no matter who and what is doing it.