# Review queues: After only upvoting, should I choose "Looks OK" or "Other action"?

Tags: support, review, voting

I recently started using the "Late answers" queue on Stack Overflow, but I suspect my question is relevant for other queues as well (though the answers may differ).

I am unclear about the **right action to take if I am content with an answer to the point of (only) having upvoted it**.

Official word (from [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/188174) on Stack Exchange Meta):

> #### *Late answers*, *First answers*, and *First questions*
>
> [...]
>
> - **Looks OK**: the post meets the site's guidelines for good questions or answers (but you're not *that* impressed with the post to cast an upvote).

This states that upvoting is incompatible with "Looks OK". However the description from the "Looks OK" button itself is strictly speaking ambiguous:

> ###### Looks OK
>
> Answer addresses the question, is unique, and is not low quality.

Similar uncertainty or confusion by other users is implicit in some places on [Stack Overflow] Meta, eg [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418021/2057969).

There is also [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280590/2057969) regarding "Triage" queues, for which upvotes are compatible with "Looks OK". Someone pointed out in a now-deleted comment that triage matters might not be relevant for other queues. This may or may not be true, but in any case SE users will be surprised if the various queues behave differently in this regard.

**What is the latest policy on the right action to choose after upvoting in the review queues?**

Comment: The button used to be called "No Action Needed" and used to be disabled once some action was taken on the post, including an up vote, hence the text in the FAQ. That it's not disabled today is a possible bug (but I'm not certain).

Comment: FYI: at the moment, [the corresponding pages in the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues) just say "Choose **Looks OK** if the answer requires no intervention." – nothing about upvoting.